# Проигрывание видео с массива байт. Android

Tags: android, массивы, потоки-данных, видео, bytearray

Нужно показывать видео на SurfaceView/TextureView/VideoView. На вход приходит массив байт. Я получаю пакеты RTP, откуда могу брать только массив байт, как перевести массив байт в картинку?

Answer (score 0):

ВОзможно вам стоит посмотреть https://github.com/ekumenlabs/AndroidStreamingClient который реализует RTP клиент, в нем вся логика получения RTP стрима выполняется android.media.MediaCodec (как части MediaPlayer).

Вам необходимо встроится в Callback onInputBufferAvailable и положить туда раскодированные пакеты с видеостримом [(отсюда)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec):

```
 MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(name);
 MediaFormat mOutputFormat; // member variable
 codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {
   @Override
   void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {
     ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);
     // fill inputBuffer with valid data <вот тут>
     …
     codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, …);
   }

   @Override
   void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId, …) {
     ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId);
     MediaFormat bufferFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(outputBufferId); // option A
     // bufferFormat is equivalent to mOutputFormat
     // outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.
     …
     codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, …);
   }

   @Override
   void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec mc, MediaFormat format) {
     // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
     // Can ignore if using getOutputFormat(outputBufferId)
     mOutputFormat = format; // option B
   }

   @Override
   void onError(…) {
     …
   }
 });
 codec.configure(format, …);
 mOutputFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(); // option B
 codec.start();
 // wait for processing to complete
 codec.stop();
 codec.release();
```